# How to know when reset pci device is completed?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, pci

I want to know when the pci reset is completed, so I assume that best option to know that is to read the device id field from the pci device configuration registries.

The device id field change to 0xffff after the reset and should to change back to the real device id after 200-400 milliseconds (probably after the ending of the reset).

I get an error from the function 'pci_read_config_word' in case of accessing it without waiting.

I don't want to guess a time number to wait.
There is another option to do the polling?

```
pci_set_pcie_reset_state(pdev, pcie_deassert_reset);

while(polling_counter < 100)
{
    pci_read_config_word(pdev, PCI_DEVICE_ID,
                         &device_id);

    if (device_id == pdev->device)
       break;

    polling_counter++;
}

// This function can failed if the reset is not completed.
pci_restore_state(pdev);
```

From the dmesg:

```
[c000000167bcb200] [c0000000000155ac] .show_stack+0x6c/0x198 (unreliable)                                                                    
[c000000167bcb2b0] [c000000000076a8c] .eeh_dn_check_failure+0x354/0x3f0                                                                      
[c000000167bcb370] [c000000000029b7c] .rtas_read_config+0x13c/0x198                                                                          
[c000000167bcb410] [c00000000039c8d0] .pci_bus_read_config_word+0xa0/0xf8                                                                    
[c000000167bcb4d0] [d000000004f6043c] .reset_device+0x23c/0x530 [mst_ppc_pci_reset]                                                          
[c000000167bcb590] [c0000000003a6254] .local_pci_probe+0x7c/0xf8                                                                             
[c000000167bcb620] [c0000000003a63a8] .__pci_device_probe+0xd8/0x128                                                                         
[c000000167bcb6d0] [c0000000003a72a8] .pci_device_probe+0x38/0x68                                                                            
[c000000167bcb760] [c0000000004d0bd8] .really_probe+0xb0/0x288                                                                               
[c000000167bcb810] [c0000000004d0e4c] .driver_probe_device+0x9c/0x110                                                                        
[c000000167bcb8a0] [c0000000004d0fbc] .__driver_attach+0xfc/0x100                                                                            
[c000000167bcb930] [c0000000004cfee4] .bus_for_each_dev+0xc4/0x118                                                                           
[c000000167bcb9e0] [c0000000004d08a8] .driver_attach+0x28/0x40                                                                               
[c000000167bcba60] [c0000000004cf3b0] .bus_add_driver+0x190/0x340                                                                            
[c000000167bcbb10] [c0000000004d1950] .driver_register+0x98/0x1b8                                                                            
[c000000167bcbbb0] [c0000000003a760c] .__pci_register_driver+0x64/0x140                                                                      
[c000000167bcbc50] [d000000004f608c0] .init+0x28/0x430 [mst_ppc_pci_reset]                                                                   
[c000000167bcbcd0] [c00000000000ab68] .do_one_initcall+0x68/0x1e0                                                                            
[c000000167bcbd90] [c00000000010893c] .SyS_init_module+0xcc/0x218                                                                            
[c000000167bcbe30] [c0000000000098ec] syscall_exit+0x0/0x40
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just real quick checked the /driver/pci.c and found this macro

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/pci.c#L143

Based on it's uses in these places I'm going to say the official way is to just wait although I'm not sure what kind of reset your doing.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/pci.c#L4672
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/pci.c#L4486

However again depending on your reset it's possible the link might reset in which case you could try using this function (no promises). 
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/pci.c#L4585

Overall it seems this wait function is what the library wants you to use. If you say what kind of reset you want to perform it might help.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/pci/pci.c#L4401

Sorry for the poor formatting I'm on phone, I'll update later if no one touches this.

Comment: Please, add macros/functions *names* into the post. In the current form your answer has no value without following the links. This is know a **link-only answer**, and that kind of answers is tended to be avoided on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi @arduic, Hi,
Thanks for the reply.
This is about hot reset:
pci_set_pcie_reset_state(pdev, pcie_hot_reset);

Comment: pci_dev_wait(struct pci_dev *dev, char *reset_type, int timeout) is not appear in pci.h